# Unable to cast object of type vb.net

Tags: vb.net, imageview, oledb

Invalid cast exception was unhandled

> The error is in "me.picturebox3.image = dt.rows(0).item("pic")

Unable to cast object of type `system.byte[]` to type `system.drawing.image`.

```
Dim dt as new datatable
Da.fill(dt)
Me.picturebox3.image = dt.rows(0).item("pic")
```

I am new in calling images from data table to picturebox. Help please..
Thanks

Comment: At which line the error message occurs? What are the types of `Da` and `Me.picturebox3`?

Comment: My da is dataAdapter "dim da as new oledb.oledbdataadapter(" select pic from table") the error is in the line me.picturebox3.image = dt.rows(0).item("pic")

Comment: Why don't you do a bit of search instead? http://www.bing.com/search?q=convert%20byte%20array%20to%20image%20in%20vb.net&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=convert%20byte%20array%20to%20image%20in%20vb.net&sc=1-37&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=CF4C07011ADF4B5EA792825BC513B579

Answer (score 2):

You need to find a way to construct an object of type `System.Drawing.Image` from the `System.Byte()` you currently have on hand.

Here's how you do it:

```
Dim bytes As Byte() = CType(dt.Rows(0).Item("pic"), Byte())
Dim ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)

Me.picturebox3.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
```

This will work as long as your `Byte()` is in a format that can be handled out of the box, i.e. JPEG, BMP etc.

Comment: I'll try this. Wait a moment

Comment: I tried the code you suggested but a new error occured. A blue line from (new memorystream(dt.rows(0).item("pic") im sorry, i dont know anything about what you said of array or byte the error says "overload resolution failed because no accesible 'new' can be called without a narrowing conversion

Comment: Use the second version

Comment: Ill try this. Wait a moment.

Comment: The error is gone and the form shows. But the pictures appear wrong. It only copies my banner. It doenst open the desired saved picture. The pictures are jpeg

Comment: @namelessaccount, well then congrats, the problem your question was originally about is solved. Obviously there's something else going on now: probably incorrect image sizing (check `SizeMode` on your `PictureBox` - most likely you want it to be `PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom`). This may warrant a separate question though as it is not related to the original error. Good luck!

Comment: Many big thanks you. Im in progress again in my little program. I have a presentation in school at monday. Big thanks man.